# I want to generate the unicode UTF-16 for a text file in python

Tags: python, character-encoding, utf-16

like in the picture, i have a normal text in a file that i want to write in unicode like that
[image]

i'm having this code, but it doesn't do the job, it just write the text as it is while i need really the utf-16 encoding to be displayed

```
with open(localOutputPath,'r') as infile:
        data = infile.read()
        #print(data)

    with open(localUtf16Path, 'w', encoding="utf-16") as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)
```

Comment: Your right side example is not UTF-16. That are Unicode escape sequences.

Comment: do you have a script for that

Answer (score 0):

Utterly useless:

```
==> type .\SO\62111029.py
```

> ```
> import io
> localOutputPath = r'd:\bat\62111029input.txt'
> localUtf16Path  = r'd:\bat\62111029output.txt'
> data = []
> with io.open(localOutputPath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
>     with io.open(localUtf16Path, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
>         for line in infile:
>             data = ''.join(['\\u' + '{:04x}'.format(ord(letter))
>                 for letter in line.rstrip('\n')]).replace('\\u0020',' ')
>             outfile.write(data + '\n')
> ```

```
==> 2>NUL del 62111029output.txt

==> type 62111029input.txt
```

> ```
> September 1, 1939
> 1 Σεπτεμβρίου 1939
> 1 сентября 1939
> 1. září 1939
> ```

```
==> .\SO\62111029.py

==> type 62111029output.txt

\u0053\u0065\u0070\u0074\u0065\u006d\u0062\u0065\u0072 \u0031\u002c \u0031\u0039\u0033\u0039
\u0031 \u03a3\u03b5\u03c0\u03c4\u03b5\u03bc\u03b2\u03c1\u03af\u03bf\u03c5 \u0031\u0039\u0033\u0039
\u0031 \u0441\u0435\u043d\u0442\u044f\u0431\u0440\u044f \u0031\u0039\u0033\u0039
\u0031\u002e \u007a\u00e1\u0159\u00ed \u0031\u0039\u0033\u0039
```