# How to convert a special character to unicode escape sequence in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

For example, I would like to convert "!" into "\u0021" in Python, as per [this](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0021/index.htm).

The following just returns the same character, i.e. "!", not the unicode escape sequence.

> print("!".encode('unicode-escape'))

Comment: I don't think that there is a easy direct way to do that for character that are still in ascii table range

Comment: you can however get the numeric value of a character with the `ord` function: `ord("!")` return 33 which is 21 in hexadecimal and get the character back with its inverse `chr`

Comment: Check [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365949/3439404).

Answer (score -1):

Something like the following needs further refinement, but it might help:

```python
hot_beverage = "☕" # == "\u2615"
coffee_cup   = "⛾" # == "\u26fe"

# `set` removes duplicates
# `sorted` returns an iterator for strings in sorted order
beverages = list(sorted(set([hot_beverage, coffee_cup])))

for beverage in beverages:
    escape_sequence = "\\u" + str(hex(ord(beverage)))[2:]
    print(escape_sequence)

print("\u2615")
print("\u26fe")
```